# Why the QLineEdit().text() doesn't work in my code?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have searched several questions about how to get input from QLineEdit.text(), but it does't work in my code. I don't know why.

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget,QPushButton,QLineEdit)

class Login_Ui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 
        self.setWindowTitle('form') 

        self.AccoutText = QLineEdit(self)
        self.AccoutText.setGeometry(140,185,180,30)
        self.username = self.AccoutText.text()####

        self.PwdText = QLineEdit(self)
        self.PwdText.setGeometry(140,220,180,30)
        self.password = self.PwdText.text()####

        self.LoginBtn = QPushButton('login',self)
        self.LoginBtn.clicked.connect(self.loginme)
        self.LoginBtn.setGeometry(140,290,180,30)
        self.show()

    def loginme(self):
        print(self.username)
        print(self.password)
        print('...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Log = Login_Ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to explain yourself more than "doesn't work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're storing the text from those `textedits` before anything is put in them.

You need to get the text from the `textedits` when the `login` button is pressed. Like this:

```
def loginme(self):
    # get the values from the textedits first
    self.username = self.AccoutText.text()
    self.password = self.PwdText.text()

    print(self.username)
    print(self.password)
    print('...')
```